# A characterization of round sphere

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $k$ dimensional compact Riemannan manifold which is isometrically embeded in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. The distance arising from the Riemannian metric is denoted by $d_g$.The Euclidian distance of two points $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ is denoted by $|x-y|$.
Assume that for every $x,y,z,w\in M$
$d_g(x,y)=d_g(z,w) \iff |x-y|=|z-w|$

Does this imply that $M$ is a round sphere?

Comment: Isn't this property you assume also true for $k$-planes (edit: meaning affine-linear subspaces) embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$?

Comment: @EricCanton it is assumed that $M$ is compact

Comment: I missed that. I'll leave my comment for other uncareful readers.

Comment: I think it is true. Let $m\in M$. Then the distance  of a geodesic of length $\epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ small enough in a direction of principal curvature can be approximated to second order in terms of the eigen-values of the first (or second? im terrible with names) fundamental form. In particular, if it is the same in both principal directions, then the principal curvatures agree up to sign. But it is known that if the second fundamental form of a surface is constant then it is a round sphere.

Comment: Of course, one have to rule out the option of negative curvature but this is clearly impossible everywhere on $M$.

Comment: Note that this would be false for a $1$-dimensional manifold embedded in $R^4$, as with $\{(5\sin t, 5\cos t, \sin 2t, \cos 2t)\}$, which has the property but is not a circle.

Comment: I think it would also be false for $3$-dimensional manifolds embedded in $R^8$, as with $\{(5u,u^2)\}$, where $u$ ranges over unit quaternions. Perhaps someone else will be able to check that case.

Comment: @S.carmeli I guess you can turn your argument into a proof. Note that since $M$ is compact, there is a point of maximal distance from the origin, where necessarily all principal curvatures are nonzero and of the same sign. And yes, it is the second fundamental form you want.

Comment: @SebastianGoette Yah, I guess that too. It was just so late yesterday that I was a little scared to write an "answer" and this is the only reason its in a comment :-)

Comment: @S.carmeli after writing my answer, I realized that you did it already :-)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\gamma$ is a geodesic in $M$.
Then there is a function $\ell$ such that $|\gamma(t_0)-\gamma(t_1)|=\ell(|t_0-t_1|)$, assuming that $|t_0-t_1|$ is small.
It follows that $\gamma$ has constant curvature.

Further, note that any two geodesics in $M$ are congruent.
In particular, $M$ has constant principle curvatures; so $M$ is a round sphere.

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  and my +1  for  your  answer